# Latest version of MySQL gives error 1064 on code that used to work fine

Tags: mysql

Many servers now a days have the latest version of MySQL - which is giving an error when running the following piece of code:

```
$drop_table = mysql_query("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `$t_ads`");
$sqls[$t_ads] = "CREATE TABLE `$t_ads` (
  `adid` int unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `adtitle` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  `addesc` longtext NOT NULL,
  `area` varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',
  `email` varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',
  `showemail` enum('0','1','2') NOT NULL default '0',
  `password` varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',
  `code` varchar(35) NOT NULL default '',
  `cityid` smallint unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `subcatid` smallint unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `price` DECIMAL( 10, 2 ) NOT NULL default '0',
  `othercontactok` enum('0','1') NOT NULL default '0',
  `hits` int unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `ip` varchar(15) NOT NULL default '',
  `verified` enum('0','1') NOT NULL default '0',
  `abused` int unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `enabled` enum('0','1') NOT NULL default '0',
  `createdon` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `expireson` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `timestamp` timestamp(14) NOT NULL,
  `paid` enum('0','1','2') NOT NULL default '2',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`adid`),
  KEY `subcatid` (`subcatid`),
  KEY `cityid` (`cityid`),
  KEY `verified` (`verified`),
  KEY `enabled` (`enabled`),
  KEY `paid` (`paid`)
) TYPE=MyISAM;";
```

Servers with an older version of mysql seem to accept this, but the new version is not accepting it at all and giving an error. I have many errors related to it since the PHP database setup is little bigger. An example of the error is below:

> `#1064` - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(14) NOT NULL, `paid` enum, NOT NULL default '2', PRIMARY KEY (`adid`), K' at line 21

Answer (score 1):

The plain SQL part of your code looks ok (just tested it with MySQL 5.6), though I'd generally advise not to use keywords like `timestamp` as a column name. The table will be created in MySQL 5.6, but you'll encounter two warnings:

1. The syntax `TIMESTAMP(14)` is deprecated and will be removed in
   MySQL 6.0. Please use `TIMESTAMP` instead
2. The syntax `TYPE=storage_engine` is deprecated and will be removed in MySQL
   6.0. Please use `ENGINE=storage_engine` instead

If this doesn't help, please post the actual MySQL version you're working with.

Answer (score 0):

Change your column name it should not be mysql keyword 'timestamp' and

chnage

```
`timestamp` timestamp(14) NOT NULL,
```

to

```
`<SOME OTHERNAME>` timestamp NOT NULL,
```